# Disable Word from creating ACLs on samba fileshare?

Tags: linux, microsoft-word, samba

I have a samba file share server that is used on a production network. When a Word document is saved, it adds ACLs to the Word document on the file share server, which denies access to the word document from other users that have permission to read/write/execute the word document. I used `setfacl` with the `-m` option to modifiy those ACLs. Is there an option in Word to disable those ACLs from being applied to the samba server? I checked settings in Word, and couldn't find anything.

Comment: Did you dig into the Word settings to see if there is anything to help with ACL's?

Comment: I did, couldn't find anything that had to do with ACLs.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the following worked out:

I added the following two definitions into the relevant smb.conf block:

```
force create mode = 0060 #Add rw bit only to group of a file
force directory mode = 0070 #Add rwx bit only to group of a directory
```

More details and explanation can be found here: https://serverfault.com/questions/562875/samba-default-file-creation-mask-calculation